# Adding animation when using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to add animations to jquery.

Currently I have a navigation bar below a fixed header. As the page scrolls, the navigation bar and the content below moves up until the navigation bar reached the top of the page where it becomes fixed. At this point a logo appears to the left of the navigation items and these items are then floated to the right of the navigation.

How can I make it so the float right isn't such a sudden jump and there is a slow or faded animation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where is your code? I cannot find it...

Comment: You are better having your animation in CSS and using `addClass` with jQuery when you want the animation to run. If you are using `float:right` you might want to replace it with `position:absolute`

Comment: Greetings, what code do you have, and can you create a simple version of your site in a fiddle jsfiddle.net, this way we can edit your code and give you feedback on that code. i can point you in the right direction but I need to see some visuals of what you have.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an animation, you need to be able to "tween" a value. This mean you need to be able to calculate steps in the value you'll give to your element.

As so, it's easy to animate position. E.g. Animate from left 10px to left 100px. You can calculate the middle steps.

That's not possible with `float` as there's no tweenable value associated with it. So, I'd say to go with absolute positioning and filling the hole it'll leave with padding.